# can not read font in Itext sharp with asp.net core 2.0

Tags: itext, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am Working with  [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp)!    I'm trying to use some type of fonts  from  wwwroot file 
But can not read the  font 
 the problem with this line of code

```
var fontPath = FontFactory.GetFont(Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "fonts//Times New Roman Bold.ttf"), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 12);
```

Comment: 1. you have the wrong Nuget link. Your link refers to an old, unsupported version. The new version is [iText 7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/) and 2. I've never seen a Times Roman font named `Times New Roman Bold.ttf`. Are you sure you aren't talking about `timesbd.ttf` (usually found under `C:\Windows\fonts`). Note that you may not have a license to move that file to another directory (which is what you seem to do).

Comment: I'm sure the type of  my font, this library is working with me with some warnings in other  project  but I do not know why it is not working now with my new project  @BrunoLowagie

Comment: OK, but if you want help, why don't you mention the error message? If the error message is "cannot read font", then there's a high chance that the path to the font is wrong. For instance: are you sure that your web application has access to the `.ttf` file? Have you tried reading the file without using iText?

Comment: There is no error appearing just does not read the font... I confirmed the validity of the font path  in  Server   
But I would like to point out that I have changed the [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp)    with [iTextiTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core)     version  and  It is Worked 
but iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core   library  Missing some of the functions that I need  @BrunoLowagie

Comment: Dear @AhmedSalim Is there a reason why you want to push obsolete versions to your customer's code base? Your links to Nuget are pointing to versions of iText that should no longer be used because they are no longer supported (not iTextSharp, not iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core). This is the correct link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/ (Of course, if you want your customer to be unhappy, feel free to do so; that will make your competitors happy.)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: _"can not read the font"_ is not a specific problem or error. Please clarify.

Answer (score -1):

you need to register the path to the fonts folder